# Ошибка при работе с MutableLiveData: non-static method getInstance() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, activity, mvvm, dagger2

Я пытаюсь создать некий Repository для хранения данных между событиями жизненного цикла Android приложения. Следую архитектуре паттерна MVVM, также использую Dagger2.

WorkData.java

```
public class WorkData {
    private boolean auth;

    public WorkData() {
        this.auth = false;
    }

    public boolean isAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public void setAuth(boolean auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }
}
```

DataRepository.java

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import dagger.Provides;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

//SingleTon
@Module
public class DataRepository {

    private MutableLiveData<WorkData> mCurrentObject;

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public MutableLiveData<WorkData> getInstance() {
        if (mCurrentObject == null) {
            mCurrentObject = new MutableLiveData<>();
            mCurrentObject.setValue(new WorkData());
        }
        return mCurrentObject;
    }
}
```

WorkDataSharedViewModel.java

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class WorkDataSharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<WorkData> selected = new MutableLiveData<WorkData>();

    private MutableLiveData<WorkData> mCurrentData;

    public MutableLiveData<WorkData> getCurrentData() {
        if (mCurrentData == null) {
            mCurrentData = DataRepository.getInstance();
        }
        return mCurrentData;
    }

    public void set(WorkData item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<WorkData> get() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

***

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //init work variables
        WorkDataSharedViewModel workData = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WorkDataSharedViewModel.class);
        workData.set(new WorkData());

***
}
```

Но при компиляции файла WorkDataSharedViewModel.java возникает ошибка:

non-static method getInstance()  cannot be referenced from a static context.

Пожалуйста подскажите, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ошибку в WorkDataSharedViewModel.java, сделал так:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;


public class WorkDataSharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<WorkData> selected = new MutableLiveData<WorkData>();

    private MutableLiveData<WorkData> mCurrentData;

    public MutableLiveData<WorkData> getCurrentData() {
        if (mCurrentData == null) {
            DataRepository dataRepository = new DataRepository();
            mCurrentData = dataRepository.getInstance();
        }
        return mCurrentData;
    }

    public void set(WorkData item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<WorkData> get() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```